# Can we run video pre-roll ads with Video.js player?

Tags: ads, video.js

Can we run video pre-roll ads with Video.js player? If yes is there any documentation how to do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run video ads with video.js players but the players should be compatible with VAST ( http://www.iab.net/guidelines/508676/digitalvideo/vsuite/vast ) .

Please check the below URL for video.js implementation.
https://github.com/PetroFrolov/vast-video-js

Answer (score 1):

You can run ads with the [video js ads plugin](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads).

You can use it in combination with [video js preroll plugin](https://github.com/dirkjanm/videojs-preroll) for easier integration.

However as far as I can tell, neither work with rtmp streaming at this point.