# How to display video advertising in wowza player before start of video?

Tags: ads, wowza

We have used Wowza player for streaming videos from external server in html. We need to show video ad before the start of the original video.
On searching in google , the solution suggests using jw player to show ads which is available only in paid version.
Is there any possibility of showing ads in video player that is of free of cost?
Is there any way to show ad by configuring in wowza server??

Please suggest a way!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's too greedy to ask for such an option.

But if you want a player side ads you can refer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368222/can-we-run-video-pre-roll-ads-with-video-js-player) asked before.

This plugin for video-js [should](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads) work. And you can always stick with JW or Bitmovin.

Server-side ads is a very tricky thing. But there are some beta implementations in a server software.